# Drools guided editor gives error "Note: No model has been defined." How to define one?

Tags: java, drools

I'm trying to follow along with the examples in the book "JBoss Drools Business Rules" (which, like most other Packt Publishing books, is a poorly edited mess of misspellings, bad edits, and errors).

The Drools UI has advanced a bit since this book was written, so I can't follow along exactly.

I've uploaded a model as a jar file, and now want to define some rules.

I navigate to packages->models and find my model

Then, on the left hand side, I say "create new->New Rule->Business Rule (guided editor)"

I create the rule, then try to modify the "when" condition, and I get that error

> Note: No model has been defined. Tip:
>   You will want to import or define a
>   model for this user interface to work
>   !

and since it doesn't know about the model, this guided interface doesn't really do much good.

Does anyone out there know how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok! I think I got it

If you select your package from the Guvnor UI LHS and click on it, you'll get a configuration menu that lets you select what uploaded jars to make available to things defined in that package.

I added the model jar I uploaded, and the rules editor stopped complaining....